# gnuplot dashed lines in aqua terminal

Tags: terminal, gnuplot

[image]I am using gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 4 on Mac OS X v10.6.8.  I'm running a gnuplot script, a simplified version of which is this:  (file1, file2,...etc are specified in the terminal before running the script)

```
reset
set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18"
set term aqua dashed
plot file1 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#FF0000",\
     file2 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#00FF00",\
     file3 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#0000FF",\
     file4 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#FF00FF",\
     file5 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#00FFFF",\
     file6 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#FF0000",\
     file7 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#00FF00",\
     file8 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#0000FF",\
     file9 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#FF00FF",\
     file10 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#00FFFF"
```

files 1-5 are one data set and files 6-10 are another. I would like files 1 through 5 to be plotted with solid lines and files 6 through 10 to be plotted with dashed lines.  Is there any way to do this in aqua terminal? According to the built-in help, "lines can be drawn either solid or dashed".  I've looked at multiple faqs and docs but the consensus seems to be that it is really difficult or impossible to do?  Additionally, does anyone know of any comprehensive documentation on the aqua terminal or on gnuplot commands in general?

**Edit:** To plot files 6-10 I have been using lw 6 to distinguish them from the 1-5 since I couldn't get dashed lines to work.  Would the script above as I have it do this correctly?  In other words, is the script doing what I think it is doing? (plotting 1-5 solid lines and 6-8 thicker lines?) I ask because in an attempt to make dashed lines, I replace "lw 6" with "lt 2".  This however results in file5 being plotted with dashed lines which is just weird.

**Edit 2:** I attached my terminal test graphic and there doesn't seem to be any mention of dashed lines?

**Edit 3:** Updated script to reflect changes made.

**Edit 4:** Graphic is now of set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18" dashed; test

[image]

Comment: in response to your edit, the linetype of the plots is probably getting incremented in gnuplot internally.  If you want file5 to be plotted with `lt 1` then you should put that in there, otherwise gnuplot just guesses.

Comment: @mgilson -- (Edited above) Ok cool, it's plotting correctly now, but all lines are solid still.

Comment: did you do `set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18" dashed` (note the `dashed` at the end).  What is the output of `show terminal`?

Comment: can you post the graphic of `set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18" dashed; test`?

Comment: @mgilson -- Oh, there the dashed lines are!

Comment: Yeah, `lt 8` is the one you should be using as I suspected.  I wonder who changed it, aqua or gnuplot?  I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too bad at all actually (at least for me on OS-X 10.5.8 with gnuplot 4.2.  I stopped building aquaterm in my newer versions of gnuplot as I don't like that terminal)  In the aqua terminal, linetype 1 is solid and linetype 2 is dashed.

```
set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18" dashed
plot sin(x) w lines lt 1 lc rgb "blue", cos(x) w lines lt 2 lc rgb "purple"
```

To see the linetypes that your version of gnuplot will use for a particular terminal, you can use the `test` command after setting the terminal (and output if the terminal needs it).

A suggestion for how your code should look:

```
reset
set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman, 18" dashed
plot file1 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#FF0000",\
     file2 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#00FF00",\
     file3 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#0000FF",\
     file4 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#FF00FF",\
     file5 u 3:10 w lines lt 1 linecolor rgb "#00FFFF",\
     file6 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#FF0000",\
     file7 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#00FF00",\
     file8 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#0000FF",\
     file9 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#FF00FF",\
     file10 u 3:10 w lines lt 2 linecolor rgb "#00FFFF"
```

**EDIT**

I just looked on a friend's computer.  for her (gnuplot 4.4.4, os-X 10.6?) linetype 8 was the first dashed linetype (highlighting the usefulness of the `test` command).

Comment: Thank you!  Where should I put the line "set term aqua dashed" though?  I just stuck it after the other "set term" line.  The plots I'm getting are very confusing and making me think my original plots were wrong to begin with.  I'm going to edit the script above to show a little more detail.

Comment: @whatsherface -- I've added what I think should work for your code.

Comment: I've tried exactly what you suggest above, with and without "dashed" but there is still no change.  It could just be this machine maybe?

Comment: @whatsherface -- possibly (sorry, I forgot the dashed in my suggestion).  I suppose it's possible something changed in aqua between 10.5 and 10.6.  It's also possible that gnuplot broke something between 4.2 and 4.4.  hopefully some other user will come along and test this for us.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway!  Turns out I need to rerun all the simulations anyway so it'll be awhile before I need to plot again. :)